# Integral that represents the volume of the solid obtained by rotating an ellipse about a line.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I was given this question to answer:

x<sup>2</sup>+ y<sup>2</sup> = 4 rotates about y = 2

I know how to find volume when I have 2 functions and their the outer and inner radius (distances from the rotation axis). What is the approach to this question? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The approach is very similar. For example, if we use shell method,

Shell width at $y$ (distance from x-axis) is $2 \sqrt{4-y^2}$.

Radial distance of the shell from $y = 2$ is $(2 - y)$ where $ - 2 \leq y \leq 2$.

Now, can you you complete the working?